# static analysis for identifying backdoors

Tags: static-analysis, executable

I am doing a research in identifying backdoors in windows .exe files. Currently I found some methods to detect.
1.String search in .exe
2.find Reffrence .dll and win32 Api calls using import table

What are the other static analysis methods to detect backdoors?

Comment: It depends on your definition of a backdoor. Example: Is intentionally inserted vulnerability a backdoor you are trying to detect ?

Comment: yes.Reverse shells,etc